# Is it possible to include composer script inside website AMP version?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, amp-html

```
 <script>jQuery(window).load(function () {jQuery('body').find('#td_uid_1_5ec7788868222 .td-element-style').each(function (index, element) {jQuery(element).css('opacity', 1);return;});});</script> <script>jQuery(window).ready(function () {// We need timeout because the content must be rendered and interpreted on client
```

How to include this script inside the AMP version of the website? This script is cause by visual composer tagDiv, and i want to include it inside AMP theme i have created using AMP Theme Framework from AMPforWP plugin.

Comment: Have you read the `<amp-script>` documentation?

Comment: I don't know if you're familiar with javascript frameworks like Vue Js or React... if yes there are some formwork can help, like nuxt js...